# How to Phrase "Continued Duties as ... Prior to Promotion" in Resume?

Tags: resume

Perhaps not the place for the question, but figured this is the best place to ask it. (If it's not, please guide me!)

I am currently updating my resume to include my current position (Team Lead) having been promoted in April from Sr. Engineer. The promotion added more duties and responsibilities on top of my normal day-to-day responsibilities from when I was a Sr. Engineer. How do I specify this in the resume (i.e., that I continue to fulfill the duties and responsibilities in my current position as Team Lead same as when I was a Sr. Engineer)?

Currently, my resumes formatting is like this:

> Company Name Company Location
>
> Current Title April 2022 - Current
>
> - Responsibility A
> - Responsibility B
> - Responsibility C
> - ...
>
> Sr. Engineer Prior Promo Month/Year - April 2022
>
> - Responsibility X
> - Responsibility Y
> - Responsibility Z

How do I phrase a bullet point under "Responsibility C" to say I continue to fulfill the responsibilities of my prior position without listing out individual bullet points, X through Z?

(Perhaps I am over-complicating things here and it really is that simple as saying, "continue to fulfill the duties and responsibilities as taken on as a Sr. Engineer prior to promotion").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like (emphasis mine):

> Company Name Company Location
>
> Current Title April 2022 - Current
>
> - **All responsibilities listed in Sr. Engineer Prior Promo Month/Year - April 2022, plus:**
> - Responsibility A
> - Responsibility B
> - Responsibility C
> - ...
>
> Sr. Engineer Prior Promo Month/Year - April 2022
>
> - Responsibility X
> - Responsibility Y
> - Responsibility Z

That is, just refer or point to such list instead of repeating every element.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for - simple and straight to the point.

Comment: Glad I could help @Dash :) welcome to The Workplace BTW

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to say?

It seems to me you want to say something like:

> New Position (april 2022 - onwards): a bit less coding, more managing, and same amount of mentoring!
> Old position: coding, mentoring

Figure out what you are trying to communicate